# Can anyone explain, why "git status" touches the .git directory?

Tags: git, bash, github, git-status

I currently maintain a project for a git-prompt for bash (https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt) and I just got a bug report (https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt/issues/97) from someone who works with Docker, who tells me, that everytime he uses the prompt, the cache is invalidated, because the `.git` directory is constantly touched.

I have looked into this, and found out, that it is the command `git status`, which touches the `.git` directory.
It seems, that only the directory entry itself and no contents are touched.
Can anyone explain, why this is needed, or is this maybe a bug in Git.

Is there a way to show all status info, without touching the .git directory?

Thanks for the help

Update:

Since the whole reason to use the `git status` command was, to determine the number of untracked files, I replaced it with `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard | wc -l`, which doesn't need a lock.

Comment: A quick glance at a `strace git status` shows that this action uses a lockfile `.git/index.lock`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strace git status` shows that this action uses the lock file `.git/index.lock`, that's why the `.git`'s mtime is updated.

`git` being cool, it uses the environment variable `GIT_INDEX_FILE` to decide which lock file to use. If unset, `git` uses `.git/index` (this is the default), but if set, `git` uses its value. From `man git`:

> `GIT_INDEX_FILE`
>
> This environment allows the specification of an alternate index file. If not specified, the default of `$GIT_DIR/index` is used.

So:

```
GIT_INDEX_FILE=banana git status
```

will not update your `.git`'s mtime.

So you now have to make a decision as whether you want to go along this path or not (which certainly has many caveats).

Good luck!

Comment: It should be remarked, that the index file has to be copied to the given new file before using the `git status`command. Otherwise git will find an empty index here.

Comment: @magicmonty One possibility is to make a link (and not copy).

Comment: But thats a bit risky, as this works completely around the idea of a locking mechanism. I suspect there is a good reason, why this files would be locked. With a link you have the possibility of a read at the same time, a write happens. In the best case there is just a wrong status but in the worst case this could lead to a corrupted index.